# How to add class on body tag if it contains hierarchical url?

Tags: javascript, jquery, url

This might be a simple question. How do I add a class to my body tag if the url is hierarchical?

For example:
I have a url:

`/coding/product/business-account/`

I want to add a class to all sub urls under `product` only.

I'm using this script code, but I think the regex is only getting the first url path on it. Is there any tweak to only just add the class under `/coding/product/` url?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // jQuery is passed to the ready function as a parameter, so we alias it with $
    // This will work for you even with wikispaces
    jQuery(function($){
        var loc = window.location.pathname.match(/^\/?(\w+)\b/);
        console.log(loc);
        if(loc) $(document.body).addClass(loc[1].toLowerCase());
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
let regex = /(?<=\/product\/)(.*)/;
let loc = regex.test(`/coding/product/business-account/`);  //regex.test(window.location.pathname)
console.log('url matched: ' + loc)
if(loc) {
    //add class to element
}
```

Comment: Nice! but how do I put it on the url path to test the url if it contains a `/product` is it this? `var loc = window.location.pathname.match(/(?<=product\/)(.*)/);`  it will give me the full url wil file extension >> business-account.php

Comment: If you want only **business-account** you can use this (which will remove the extension) `/(?<=product\/).*(?=\.[0-9a-z]+$)/` if you only want to check the url is under product then `let bool = regex.test(window.location.pathname)` will return true if url has **product/**

Comment: Ah sorry my comment got you confused.. Want I want is whenever there's a url that has an extension `/product` it will add a classname lets say the class is `is-product`. So every url that contains the parent url `/product` it will automatically add that class. For example: `/product/business`, `/product/cards`, `/product/bank`. All of these will add a class `is-product`.